# ExoPlayer not loading Ads from external VAST url

Tags: android, ads, exoplayer, imasdk

I am trying to load VAST URL in ExoPlayer.

I get success while trying this url [pubads](https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/ad_rule_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&ad_rule=1&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vmap&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ar%3Dpremidpostoptimizedpod&cmsid=496&vid=short_onecue&correlator=)

But I am trying with my own VAST URL , It is not working
[url](https://agasthyapix.yodser.com/xml/2qFtK5lJ2UK0rLkk8sOoFQ.xml)

Error Showing: howing No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Is it posible to use external ads in ExoPlayer with IMA SDK .

Comment: Is it possible to load external server URL in IMA SDK

Comment: have you got success on showing ad?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and reading, I just found the solution to this issue

First of all, this is a whole new topic for me and I don't even know what is a VAST ad tag URL

So I will answer this question as a beginner only for beginners

First of all we need to understand what is VAST ad tag URL

**VAST**

VAST stands for **Video Ad Serving Template**. Simply put, it’s an XML script developed by the IAB. The most popular ad standard, VAST creates a communication link between the ad server and the video player

So we need a VAST server to host the URL

This is what I missed understanding.

The exoplayer support VAST URL from a VAST server, The documentation explained everything briefly.

So simply you can load any custom VAST URL in any VAST supported Video player